# How can I put together two consults with different inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this tables:

TABLE tema

```
+---------+-------------+
| tema_id | nombre      |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 | Aprender    |
|       4 | Justicia    |
|       2 | Pensamiento |
|       3 | Vida        |
+---------+-------------+
```

TABLE frase (phrases by author)

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
| id | autor_id | texto                                  |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 |        2 | Pienso, luego existo                   |
|  2 |        1 | Aprender sin pensar es trabajo perdido |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

TABLE tema_frase (relation with table frase and tema)

```
+----------+---------+
| frase_id | tema_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       2 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        2 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

TABLE author (author of phrases)

```
+----+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| id | nombre    | descripcion                            |
+----+-----------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | Confucio  | Pensador chino                         |
|  2 | Descartes | FilÃ³sofo y matemÃ¡tico francÃ©s       |
+----+-----------+----------------------------------------+
```

How I want to show :
TABLE

```
+------------+------------------+----------------------------+
| autor      | phrases          | themes                     |
+------------+------------------+----------------------------+
| Confucio   | Pensador chino   | Pensamiento                |
| Descartes  | FilÃ³sofo y      | Pensamiento, aprender      |
+------------+------------------+----------------------------+
```

I know show phrases with themes, and phrases with author, but i don't know how to make it together because I need put in 'FROM' two tables and I can't because of INNERS JOINS:

**Consult with phrase and theme:**

`SELECT frase.texto as frase, group_concat(tema.nombre separator ", ") as temas FROM tema_frase INNER JOIN tema ON tema_frase.tema_id=tema.tema_id INNER JOIN frase ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id GROUP BY frase.texto`

**Consult with phrase and author:**

`SELECT autor.nombre as Autor, frase.texto as Frases FROM frase INNER JOIN autor ON autor.id=frase.autor_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join `autor` to the first query, and add the author to the `group by`:

```
SELECT 
  autor.nombre as Autor, 
  frase.texto as frase, 
  group_concat(tema.nombre separator ", ") as temas 
FROM tema_frase 
INNER JOIN tema ON tema_frase.tema_id=tema.tema_id 
INNER JOIN frase ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id 
INNER JOIN autor ON autor.id=frase.autor_id
GROUP BY autor.nombre, frase.texto
```